# Form attribute to several forms

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been searching but couldn't find anything. Is it possible to use the form attribute to target more than one form?

```
<select name="users" form="form1">...</select>
```

For example, if I wanted this select to be used on form1 as it is but also on form2. Can I use something like...

```
<select name="users" form="form1; form2">...</select>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried it..??
because as what I read, it can be done.
Just make sure that the form attribute value is/are the target form's id.

Comment: do you have nested forms?

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work... They are not nested forms...